# Cordovawebview sendjavascript deprecated

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Cordova Web View sendjavascript is deprecated and it not working for me.
My java code is:

```
public static void sendJavascript(JSONObject _json) {
    String _d = "javascript:" + gECB + "(" + _json.toString() + ")";
    Log.v(TAG, "sendJavascript: " + _d);
    Log.i(TAG,_d);
    if (gECB != null && gWebView != null) {
        gWebView.sendJavascript(_d);//deprecated method
    }
}
```

My java script code :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){

       window.plugins.pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {
            ecb      : 'onNotificationGCM',
            senderID : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        });

    // Method to handle device registration for Android.
        var onNotificationGCM = function(e) {
            if('registered' === e.event) {
                // Successfully registered device.
                alert(e.regid);
            }
            else if('error' === e.event) {
                // Failed to register device.
                alert(e.msg);
            }
            else if('message' === e.event) {
                //mesage recived 
                alert(e.payload.message);
            }

        };


        // result contains any message sent from the plugin call
        function successHandler (result) {
            alert('gcm result = ' + result);
        }

        // result contains any error description text returned from the plugin call
        function errorHandler (error) {
            alert('error = ' + error);
        }   
    });
```

Deprecated details :https://apache.googlesource.com/cordova-android/+/3.6.1/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java

Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:
`gWebView.loadUrl("javascript:myJavaScriptFuntion();");`